# How to print html using echo php function

Tags: php, html

In my wordpress template

```
HTML: 

 <li style="background-image: url(<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/icon/facebook.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<a>facebook</a>
</li>
```

I want to echo this using php

I tried above html in php using echo '' ;

```
 <?php 

    echo '<li style="background-image: url(<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/icon/facebook.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;">
    <a>facebook</a>
    </li>';

?>
```

help me echoing the proper code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<li style=\"background-image: url('.bloginfo('template_url').'/images/icon/facebook.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;\">
    <a>facebook</a>
    </li>';
```

You need to:

- Escape quotes
- Concatenate the function. Don't open PHP tags while they are open

But better:

- Do not echo HTML. Drop PHP tags and just writw the HTML:

> ```
>    ?>
>     <li style="background-image: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>'/images/icon/facebook.png);
>        background-repeat:no-repeat;">
>        <a>facebook</a>
>        </li>
>  <?php
> ```

Comment: I know this is not to best , but This is needful while looping list items using php loops.

Comment: Why do you think so? `<?php foreach($items as $item): ?> HTML HERE <?php endforeach; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
   <?php
      echo '<li style="background-image: url(' . bloginfo("template_url") . '/images/icon/facebook.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;"><a>facebook</a></li>';
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
 <?php 

    echo '<li style="background-image: url('.bloginfo("template_url").'/images/icon/facebook.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;">
    <a>facebook</a>
    </li>';

?>
```

OR HTML Style

```
<li style="background-image: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon/facebook.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<a>facebook</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

get_bloginfo function return the value while bloginfo echo it.

```
<?php 
    echo '<li style="background-image: url('. get_bloginfo("template_url") .'/images/icon/facebook.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
    <a href="#">facebook</a>
    </li>';
?>
```